# .webm video file isn't working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, fullpage.js, webm

I'm currently working on building a website that has full page videos as backgrounds. The plan is to make a play button on top of the video that allows the user to watch the full-length piece with sound (embedded from Vimeo). I am running FullPage.js by Alvaro Trigo.

I am converting my video using VLC player from an Apple ProRes .MOV file. I create two web versions, an mp4 (h.264) for safari and a webm (vP8) for Chrome/Firefox.

For some reason I cant get the WebM video file to work in Firefox. It loads just fine in Chrome. When I try to open the file (from the server) it says "Video cannot be played because the file is corrupt".

I set up the MIME files on my server (I use BlueHost) and the content type says it is a video/webm but still no luck. Is this a Firefox issue or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

[video link](http://www.triggervision.tv/content/borderlinestupidfixed.webm)

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the file. VLC says it's nearly an hour long, but it stops playing after a few seconds. The progress bar scrubber is also acting strange in Chrome.

Comment: I figured that wasn't common. I tried the converting the .mov file again and it did the same thing (it says 2:08:30 or something this time). I also tried a different file to see if it is a problem with VLC and the timecode looks normal. It plays in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. Should I assume its problem with VLC?

Comment: Maybe, could also be a problem with a library VLC uses. I would recommend using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I downloaded it, I'm new to code but I will try and report back. Thanks